# Need a kind of matrix for data entry

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to establish some kind of matrix for the number of days needed to go from point A to point B.

This should looks like this:

[image]

Each origin/destination point is stored in a table (named Stop):

```
public class Stop
{
    [Key]
    public int StopID { get; set; }
    public string StopCode { get; set; }
}
```

The data of the matrix should be stored in another table:

```
public class Matrix
{
    [Key]
    public int MatrixID { get; set; }
    public int OriginStopID { get; set; }
    public int DestinationStopID { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfDays { get; set; }
}
```

I need a view to allow the user to entry data in this matrix. **How can I achieve this?** I don't have any idea.

Thanks.

Comment: do you have any solution for this? i also have this kind of problem.

Answer (score 0):

U can use a complex model based on a two viewmodels to create form or use something simple based on array.

Here is very simple example of what can be done (I can make more complicated example with two ViewModels if needed).

ViewModel:

```
public class TestViewModel
{
    public int[][] Matrix { get; set; }

    public TestViewModel()
    {            
    }

    public TestViewModel(string i)
    {
        Matrix = new int[4][] { new int[4] { 1, 2, 3, 4 }, new int[4] { 1, 2, 3, 4 }, new int[4] { 1, 2, 3, 4 }, new int[4] { 1, 2, 3, 4 } };
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Test()
    {
        return View(new TestViewModel("sa"));
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Test(TestViewModel model)
    {
        //some business logic goes here
        //ViewModel to Model convertion goes here
        return View(model);
    }
```

View:

```
@model TestViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="form_block">
        @for (int i = 0; i<Model.Matrix.Length;i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j<Model.Matrix[i].Length;j++)
            {
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.Matrix[i][j])
            }
        }
    </div>
    <div class="submit_block">
        <input type="submit" value="Сохранить изменения" />
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll try your solution asap and I'll keep you in touch.